# ¿Cómo obtener el nombre de un método como un String dentro del propio método?

Tags: java

Explico con un ejemplo lo que intento conseguir.

Tengo el siguiente método y quiero obtener solo (sin información adicional) como se llama dentro del propio método.

Ejemplo con el String "foo" harcodeado.

```
public void foo(){
    System.out.println("foo");
}
```

Lo que necesito es obtener lo mismo pero haciendo uso de algún método interno de las librerías de java y que no incluya información adicional.

Comment: **Si, es posible**. Qué has intentado? primero has de investigar y probar, despues explicarnos qué has probado y por que no te ha funcionado: errores, resultado no es el esperado ... etc. Mira [ask] para mejorar la calidad de tu pregunta. Un saludo

Comment: Dices "pero nunca he conseguido dar con la solución correcta" pero no muestras nada de lo que has intentado ... asi parece que no has intentado nada. Además mostrar las pruebas sirve para descartar soluciones a la hora de ayudarte. Por favor, edita la pregunta .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Puedes obtener el nombre del método llamando a [`getMethodName()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StackTraceElement.html#getMethodName()) de la Clase `StackTraceElement`.

Puedes incluso obtener los nombres de métodos por orden descendente de llamada, como muestra en el ejemplo la llamada a `getAllMethods();` dentro de `foo()`:

### Código:

<kbd>[**`VER DEMO EN REXTESTER`**](http://rextester.com/YASMK63598)</kbd>

```
class Rextester
{  
    public static void main(String args[])
    {

        foo();
    }

    public static void foo ()
    {
        
        int intTotalMetodos = Rextester.class.getDeclaredMethods().length;
        String sMethodName = new String (Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1].getMethodName());
        String sClassName  = new String (Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1].getClassName());


        System.out.println("Esta clase se llama: "+sClassName+"\n");
        System.out.println("Tiene: "+intTotalMetodos+" métodos\n");

        System.out.println("Este método se llama: "+sMethodName+"\n");
        
        /*
         * Se puede obtener el nombre de métodos 
         * por orden descendente de llamada
        */
        
        getAllMethods(intTotalMetodos);        
    }


    public static void getAllMethods(int intTotalMetodos) 
    {
      int i;

      System.out.println("------------------------------------------\n");
      System.out.println("Nombres de métodos por orden descendente: \n");

      for( i = 1; i <= intTotalMetodos; i++ ) {
         System.out.println("El método "+i+" se llama: "+Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[i].
         getMethodName());
      }
   }
}
```

---

### Resultado:

```
Esta clase se llama: Rextester

Tiene: 3 métodos

Este método se llama: foo

------------------------------------------

Nombres de métodos por orden descendente: 

El método 1 se llama: getAllMethods
El método 2 se llama: foo
El método 3 se llama: main
```

Answer (score 2):

Sí que puedes obtener el nombre del método con la siguiente instrucción:

```
String name = new Object(){}.getClass().getEnclosingMethod().getName();
```

Ahora bien, haciendo referencia a [esta respuesta de SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5891326/8025091), cada vez que ejecutas esa función te va a obtener la clase entera para, de esa clase, sacar el método que estás utilizando, y eso puede generar problemas de rendimiento ya que guarda toda la clase en memoria. Si este método solo lo vas a utilizar en alguna ocasión muy específica no debería dar problemas de memoria.

Answer (score 2):

Si ejecutas este método dentro de otro método obtendrás el nombre del método ejecutándose en ese momento:

```
public static String getMethodName() {

    // Verficamos que exista
    if (Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace().length>2) {
        return Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[2].getMethodName();
    } else {
        return "undefined";
    }
}
```

A continuación adjunto tu ejemplo:

```
public void foo(){
    System.out.println("Hello "+getMethodName());
}
```

Imprimirá:

```
Hello foo
```