# ¿Como puedo mostrar el nombre de una función en el catch?

Tags: java, funciones, try-catch

En una función que contiene try-catch necesito mostrar dentro del catch el nombre de la función misma para que al fallar, la misma muestre la función donde falla.
¿Es esto posible?

Comment: No sé si te refieres a esto: **[¿Cómo obtener el nombre de un método como un String dentro del propio método](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/75319/29967)**

Comment: ¿Quieres el nombre de la función donde salta la excepción, o dónde está el catch? Pueden no ser lo mismo.

Comment: Busco el nombre de la función donde salta la excepción. Es decir, si mi función se llama verNombres y falla la conexión a una base de datos que salga el nombre de la función verNombres.

Comment: Aunque para depurar, ya tienes este método: **[printStackTrace()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#printStackTrace())**

Comment: Si, lo se, pero es en plan para encontrar un problema más rápido.

Comment: Entonces, verifica el enlace de mi primer comentario.

Comment: En realidad es mucho más rápido el stacktrace. Te dice si el error es en tu método o en un método que llamas, el número de línea, mensaje de error.

Comment: Pensándolo bien es tontería lo que quería hacer.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con

```
String name = new Object(){}.getClass().getEnclosingMethod().getName();
```

o

```
Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()
```

Comment: ¿Podrías añadir alguna explicación del código? Así, seguro que resultará más útil para todos :) Gracias... ¡y bienvenido/a a [es.so]!