# ¿Cómo saber el método que llama a otro en java?

Tags: java

Estoy usando *Netbeans 8.2* y *Java 8* en un *SO Windows*.

Tengo tres clases en java *ClaseA*, *ClaseB* y *ClaseC*.

En *ClaseC* tengo un método estático *xxx()*, que será llamado por diversos métodos desde *ClaseA* y *ClaseB*.

¿Cómo puedo saber, mediante código, dentro del método *xxx()* desde que clase y método se le está invocando en cada llamada?

> Editado: añado una solución

Una posible solución sería añadir lo siguiente dentro del método *xxx()*:

```
String sMethodName =
    new String(Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[2].getMethodName());
String sClassName  =
    new String(Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[2].getClassName());
System.out.println("@ Called from " + sClassName + "/" + sMethodName + "()");
```

Se imprimirá algo así cuando se invoca al método, digamos desde *foo()* de *ClaseA*:

```
@ Called from sometests.ClaseA / foo()
```

Y si se quiere encapsular se lo anterior en un método, se puede crear una clase, p.e.:

```
public class Trace {

      public static void showCaller() {
            String methodName = Thread.currentThread()
                .getStackTrace()[3]
                .getMethodName( );
            String className  = Thread.currentThread()
                .getStackTrace()[3]
                .getClassName( );

            System.out.println(
                "Called from " + className + " / " + methodName + "()");
        }
} // class
```

y sólo hay que poner `Trace.showCaller();` en el método *xxx()*

Comment: click derecho en el metodo y elegir "find usages"

Comment: Cuando leí tu pregunta [me acordé mucho de esta otra pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/75319/29967).

Comment: disculpa, que IDE usas ?

Comment: @A. Cedano, a partir del código de la pregunta que enlazas se obtiene fácilmente una solución (la añadiré al final de mi pregunta). El caso es que alguna vez hice pruebas de trazado con ***getStackTrace*** y no acabe de obtener los resultados que esperaba.

Answer (score 2):

Puedes hacerlo usando la clase `StackTraceElement` y una llamada a `Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()`

```
StackTraceElement[] elements = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();
String class = elements[2].getClassName();
String method = elements[2].getMethodName();
```

[Fuente](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069066/get-current-stack-trace-in-java)

PD: Ojo la posición tiene que ser la 2 para obtener la clase que llamó.

Comment: Hola, acababa de poner una respuesta similar en mi pregunta. No se si habrá más soluciones o mejores. Te doy un voto positivo. Saludos.