# ¿Cómo obtener el nombre de un método y compararlo con un String?

Tags: java, string, poo, comparaciones

Estoy desarrollando un programa que dibuja carácteres y para cada carácter tengo un método con unas coordenadas definidas, de la siguiente forma:

```
public void L(double pos_x,double pos_y){
    GraphicsContext gc = panel_canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
    //L PARTE ARRIBA
    gc.beginPath();
    gc.setStroke(javafx.scene.paint.Color.BLACK);
    gc.moveTo(pos_x, pos_y);
    gc.bezierCurveTo(pos_x, pos_y - 60, pos_x + 50, pos_y - 30, pos_x, pos_y - 30);

    //PARTE ABAJO
    gc.moveTo(pos_x + 15, pos_y);
    gc.bezierCurveTo(pos_x - 30, pos_y, pos_x, pos_y + 10, pos_x, pos_y);
    gc.stroke();
    gc.closePath();

}
```

Y necesito saber el nombre del método que coincida con el carácter seleccionado para dibujar.

Para ello he pensado crear un bucle que vaya buscando método por método aquel que coincida con el cáracter, y una vez encontrado usarlo.

Una solución que plantee era usar un switch para cada carácter:

```
public void Letra(int ascii){
    switch (ascii){
        case 76:
            L();
        case 77:
            M();
        //Y así sucesivamente    
            
    }

}
```

Pero considero que es demasiado código considerando que deben ser 27 cáracteres más símbolos especiales.

He buscado inspiración en [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/75313/c%C3%B3mo-obtener-el-nombre-de-un-m%C3%A9todo-como-un-string-dentro-del-propio-m%C3%A9todo#:%7E:text=S%C3%AD%20que%20puedes%20obtener%20el,getClass().) realizada por otro programador, pero unicamente funciona si estás dentro del método y mi idea es primero comparar el nombre y luego ingresar al método correspondiente.

Cualquier información es valiosa.

Gracias.

Comment: que has intentado? por favor asegurate de tener un [mcve]

Comment: No se si sea la solución adecuada a tu problema, pero lo que intentas hacer se conoce como reflection. Busca informacion sobre ello y checa las respuestas de [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/160970/8838721).